# What is the vertical unit vector that passes through the curve $x=2t$ , $y=t^2$ at the point $(-2,1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> What is the vertical unit vector that passes through the curve $x=2t$
> , $y=t^2$ at the point $(-2,1)$?
>
> $1)\frac{i-j}{\sqrt2}\qquad2)\frac{i-j}{2}\qquad3)\frac{i+j}{\sqrt2}\qquad4)\frac{i+j}{2}\qquad$

Here by vertical vector at the point $(-2,1)$ I mean a vector that is vertical to the tangent vector to the curve at this point (I emphasized on it because I'm not sure if I used the correct word for it).

I tried writing the curve as $y=\frac{x^2}4$ . And the vertical line at the point $(-2,1)$ has the equation $y=x+3$. But I don't know how to express it as a unit vector.

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper term is **normal** vector, in the sense that it is a vector that is **perpendicular** to the tangent vector at a given point.

Note that two vectors are perpendicular to each other if the product of their slopes is $-1$.  So the idea is to calculate the slope of the tangent line $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt},$$ then note that the normal vector will have slope $$-\frac{dx}{dy} = - \frac{dx/dt}{dy/dt}.$$  Then evaluate this slope for a choice of $t$ corresponding to $(x(t), y(t)) = (-2, 1)$.  Finally, normalize the length of the vector; i.e., what is the appropriate scaling factor so that it has length $1$?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the slope is $1$ but I don't know how to find a vector that passes through $(-2,1)$ and has the slope one.